# Invalid use of group function when i use avg with count and sum

Tags: mysql, sql, average

What is the problem with my query ?

```
select p.name, p.photo, (
        SELECT AVG(count(ra.id_prof)/sum(ra.rate))
        FROM  rating ra
        WHERE  ra.id_prof = p.id) as rating  
from prof_table p, matier_prof mp, matiere m, niveau ni
where p.id=mp.id_prof and mp.id_matiere=m.id_mat and m.id_niv=ni.id_niv
having p.name like '%word%' or p.email like '%word%' or p.adresse like '%word%' or 
    p.biographie like '%word%' or m.matiere like '%word%' or ni.niveau like '%word%'
```

Comment: Ask another question with sample data and desired results.  Your query makes no sense.

Comment: You can't put the result of a aggregate function into another aggregate function: `avg(count()/sum())`

Comment: There are several problems with your query. First of all you are using an old join syntax (comma-separated joins) that was made redundant in 1992. Why do you use that??? Then you aggregate (COUNT, SUM), but why do you want to aggregate the aggregates (AVG)? Then you are using a HAVING clause on columns that you haven't grouped by and that aren't aggregates either. Better do as Gordon suggests; tell us what you want to achieve. It's probably rather simple.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you so much your comment had the answer the problem is the AVG it's a stuppid mistake thank you and i'm sorry for this stuppid question

Comment: It looks like the attempt at double aggregation is the biggest issue here (since it will result in an error). The old JOIN style syntax is ugly, but will run. The HAVING clause is pointless, all of those conditions should be moved to the WHERE clause.Sample data and desired results will help us steer you to working solution.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want `AVG(ra.rate)`? That will be the same as `SUM(ra.rate)/COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @Amine Choukri: As mentioned there are more issues. Adding to what I already said, it seems to me you want an `EXISTS` clause on  m.matiere and ni.niveau rather than joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mentioned your issues in the comments section to your request already. This may be what you are after: Select from prof_table where the word can be found in one of its columns or a matching matiere or niveau exists.

```
select 
  p.name, 
  p.photo, 
  (select avg(ra.rate) from rating ra where ra.id_prof = p.id) as rating  
from prof_table p
where p.name like '%word%' 
or p.email like '%word%' 
or p.adresse like '%word%' 
or p.biographie like '%word%' 
or p.id in
(
  select mp.id_prof 
  from matier_prof mp
  join matiere m on m.id_mat = mp.id_matiere
  left join niveau ni on ni.id_niv = m.id_niv
  where m.matiere like '%word%' or ni.niveau like '%word%'
);
```